# Very slow on USB i/o

Tags: linux, usb-flash-drive, rsync

(Disclaimer: Linux noob switching from Windows 7 to Linux.)
I have a dual-boot PC with 3rd gen core i5 CPU (4 real cores), 12GB RAM and a 240GB Samsung EVO850 SSD. This system is not the fastest under the sun but it's no slouch either and normally, everything is smooth and fluid and well-behaved, both under Windows 7/64 and the Debian stretch variety I'm using.

However, I've just copied (with rsync -aW) a rather large directory of .jpg files (~50GB) from the SSD to a USB3.0 stick. The stick's recognised as USB3, I've checked that with lsusb and though it has a nominal write speed of ~90MB/s, it seemed the copy wasn't much faster than 25MB/s. Both partitions are NTFS-formatted, no compression.

However, the real problem is that during the copy process, the PC became almost unusable. Almost any browser activity (Palemoon) like loading a new page or even just adding a bookmark resulted in 30, 40, 50 seconds of complete standstill (I first thought the browser was dead but it was just totally incommunicado for nearly a minute). I checked in a terminal window with htop, none of the 4 cores had more than 5% load over any 10 second period, memory use was well below 1GB. In the same terminal a df command took more than 40 seconds to complete and sometimes the command line was dead as well for some 5 or 10 seconds.

This looks like a very bad case of a severe i/o bottleneck somewhere... so I have retried the same scenario and given the rsync process a ionice mode of idle and renice'd it to be as nice as possible. This helped to some extent but the PC is still far from being usable.

I have done and still do the same or very similar jobs with the exact same hardware under Windows 7/64 and while the system is clearly not as sprightly as under zero load it remains definitely on the usable side.

I do hope there's a better way to copy $BIG_DATA to a USB stick than that... because I'd have been better off to actually boot into Windows, do the copy there and then reboot into Debian.

Has anyone got some good ideas as to how I can make things more fluid?
(I don't care much whether the copy takes a couple of minutes more as long as it's running in the background and I can work more or less as normal in the foreground.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rsync pushes the disks to their maximum speeds and you should not expect anything else
to be responsive. Loading programs will contend for access with the drives,
and even swap will be slow.

Solutions might be :

- Use the `--drop-cache` option in rsync (not available in all versions)
- Use [nocache](https://github.com/Feh/nocache), already available as package on some distributions
- [Huge pages](https://lwn.net/Articles/467328/) may still be a problem in Linux,
  but is easily solved by running `watch -n 5 sync`, or by more advanced
  [radical solutions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25691/17660)
  that are not for a noob
- Mounting your filesystems with `noatime` in `/etc/fstab` will cut down on timestamp writes, if you have an enormous amount of small files
- Some other methods that also require good knowledge, understanding (and backup) are :

  ```
  # hopefully better multitasking I/O performance
  echo 20 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_ratio

  # Try to keep at least 100MB of free RAM at all times
  echo 100000 > /proc/sys/vm/min_free_kbytes

  # Default 100 - try more aggressively to reclaim inodes, etc from cache
  echo 160 > /proc/sys/vm/vfs_cache_pressure
  ```

Comment: "Rsync pushes the disks to their maximum speeds..." So perhaps rsync is the wrong tool for this sort of job? And thanks for the other hints, I will take a look.

Comment: My local rsync doesn't include the --drop-cache patch, but nocache seems to help significantly, although the machine still seems less "fluid" than under Windows. Hard to say whether any of the other options have a discernible effect... Thanks for your answer, upvoted.

Comment: The I/O systems of Windows and Linux are radically different, so there will be differences. In most cases Linux wins on speed, but not all.

Comment: I take your word for it:-/  I've also added transparent_hugepage=never to my kernel options... I will monitor the behaviour for a while to see whether this has an adverse effect. From what I've read this might be a good idea anyway for a non-server PC.